# Force Remove a Folder in-use using Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, directory

I've created a script which at the end deletes all the associated files, self-destructs by deleting itself, and then it's supposed to delete the folder it is contained in as well.

I've tried several ways of closing Windows Explorer, searching through active processes and killing any related processes, but still cannot successfully delete the folder despite being able to self-destruct the script itself.

```
Set-Location -Path $PSScriptRoot

Remove-Item -Path $PSScriptRoot\Mobile -Force -Recurse

Remove-Item -Path $PSScriptRoot\NoMobile -Force -Recurse

Remove-Item -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source -Force -Recurse

Set-Location ..

Remove-Item $foldername -Force -Recurse
```

The last line throws an error that "The process cannot access the file...because it is being used by another process".

Any thoughts?

Comment: you may be going about it the wrong way. Can you post the script or the part that is giving you an issue. It looks like you can delete the files based set varaiables in your script.

Comment: It's the last line which is giving me the issue. The first two removes delete the subfolders, the third deletes the script itself, and the last is intended to delete the folder which was originally storing the script and the subfolders. I can give you an example of the error below.

Comment: `Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Users\<user>\<folder>\40th Anniversary Signatures: The process 
cannot access the file 'C:\Users\<user>\<folder>\40th Anniversary Signatures' because it is being used by another process.
At C:\Users\<user>\<folder>\40th Anniversary Signatures\Install Signatures.ps1:163 char:1
+ Remove-Item $foldername -Force -Recurse
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\<user>...sary Signatures:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand`

Comment: Had to remove a lot of characters above to not go over the character limit.

For reference, $foldername is actually "40th Anniversary Signatures" and some personal information was replaced with <user> and <folder>.

Answer (score 0):

This may be not the answer you might be expecting right now but posting it so that it might be helpful if someone comes into this thread.

I happen to face issue in deleting the file then after help from co-worker I found that file was open in the editor or on some other user machine. I got to follow the below document to find out who had the file open and then close those files and tried to perform delete operation and this time it worked as expected. Please find the document to figure out who happen to have the file open which you are trying to delete.

https://techgoeasy.com/how-to-tell-who-has-a-file-open-in-windows/

Comment: This is a different I believe in what I'm asking here. In my case, the script itself is likely maintaining a lock on the folders. I was looking for a way to have this script copy the temporary files it needed on a user's machine, do what it needs to do, then remove itself as it's no longer needed.